# How to add blank space while making rar or zip file

Tags: java

i searched for the way to make .rar or .zip files using java, found that JUnRar can do it. (Please recommend any other way if you know).

But my main question is how to make that `.rar` or `.zip` file the size i want to.

For example if folder size is 30mb then how to make `.rar/.zip` for example 100mb from that folder?

Comment: I'd be surprised if any API makes that easy, as it's such an unusual use case. Perhaps you could generate garbage data to fill out your .zip?

Comment: Why do you want to *increase* the size of a compressed archive filed?

Comment: Or how to make garbage files?

Comment: Create files with random data I suppose..